# Media upload takes too long

Tags: uploads

When uploading an image into media library of my WordPress admin side, it take's too long time to load the image.

Comment: so what is the question? please edit the question, be explicit about what you are asking and supply as many relevant details as possible

Comment: Define too long? Ten seconds? Ten minutes?

Comment: it takes approx up to 1 minute.

Answer (score -1):

Please check you file size first, if it's too large or heavy wait. it will take time. by default WordPress upload file size limited to 2MB only, so you have to upload less than it or you have to increase the upload file size limit.

Comment: the OP said it is slow, not that it fails

Comment: It also takes time for uploading a 130kb image file. when we upload a new image it starts the process to upload the file but at the end of the process, it stops and then after some time image will be load.